# Alter values of some columns before returning to user in Laravel sql server

Tags: encryption, laravel-5, sql-server-2012

I have some tables and each table there are few columns in which we are saving encrypted data. I am able to encrypt data before saving updating into database. But I don't know the process of how can i decrypt them before showing to user when I will run select queries.

I am using **LARAVEL 5.4** as front end. I have done this, if I follow elequent model to fetch data but it is failing in case of query builder.

Is there any way without using elequent to alter or decrypt data before showing to users. There are lots of place where I am using select query as per system needs.  I am not sure, but can this problem be solved by listening any event in laravel?

So, I can't manually write decrypt function to first get row from database and then decrypt them and then return to users. My backend database is **SQL SERVER**.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `Post` model with an encrypted `body` value. The following model would decrypt the data before returning it to the user.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post's body.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBodyAttribute($value)
    {
        return decrypt($value);
    }
}
```

The `getBodyAttribute` is a mutator. You can read more about mutators [in the Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

So now the following code would return the decrypted value of the body:

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$decryptedValue = $post->body;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already did this and doing with this way, I am getting the expected output. But it is restricting me to use elequont model. Let's suppose if I use DB::table('posts')->where('id', 1)->first();. then your solution will not work.